# What are PDFs measured in?

Tags: pdf

I'm using iTextSharp to apply rectangles to a PDF. It uses XY coordinates. I was wondering what type of measurement does PDF use? I know in Access uses twips for example.

Comment: I'de say it's in mm but why don't you make your own tests?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Measurements are in [PDF units](http://www.activepdf.com/support/knowledgebase/view.cfm?tk=dc&kb=11867):

> The PDF specification defines space in
>   a PDF file such that 72 PDF units is
>   equal to 1 inch. Therefore, an 8 1/2"
>   x 11" page would convert to 612 PDF
>   units by 792 PDF units.

You might also want to read up on the [PDF coordinate system](http://www.activepdf.com/support/knowledgebase/view.cfm?tk=rl&kb=11866)

Comment: Is there a PDF designer that can tell me what the X,Y position is when i mouse over the PDF? I have not seen that function in Adobe Reader or FoxIt Reader. Its sorta the same functionality that paint has to tell you what X,Y position the mouse is in at the bottom of the window. Thank you!

Comment: @afutrell: Not that I'm aware of, I'm afraid... you could try loading it in into Inkscape, which I believe supports PDF to at least some extent.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently PDF has it's own measurements.

72 PDF units is equal to 1 inch

See this link for conversion to inches:
http://www.activepdf.com/support/knowledgebase/view.cfm?tk=dc&kb=11867